# Why are custom error pages not working for 404 errors

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have set up a page to handle errors that occur in a website I work on using web.config. I have used the customErrors section in web.config to do this, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

Here is the relevant section

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="page.aspx?IDDataTreeMenu=357">
     <error statusCode="403" redirect="page.aspx?IDDataTreeMenu=357"/>
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="page.aspx?IDDataTreeMenu=357" />
  </customErrors>
```

This seems to work for all errors except 404. I just get the standard IIS 404 error when accessing a URL that doesn't exist.

What am I missing here?

This site is hosted on a shared server, so changing settings in IIS is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with the ISP and see if they have a place where you can insert a reference to your own custom 404 page.

At Network Solutions they give you a control panel and a page where you can set this up.

Comment: Surprisingly they don't have a control panel where I can change this sort of thing.

Comment: @Sean just to know, why is this closed? I'm facing the same error not being able to redirect in 404 http error to a custom error page.
open ticket - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715261/redirecting-to-custom-error-pages-in-azure-application-service-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

```
    <httpErrors>
        <clear />
        <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" path="/404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```