# Redirecting to custom error pages in Azure Application service doesn't work

Tags: azure-web-app-service, web-config, http-error, azure-appservice

I'm trying to redirect in case of an http error to a error page hosted in an external url making use of the element `<httpErrors>` in my web.config file in server.
Currently I have the following configuration

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="Redirect">
      <error statusCode="404" path="https://my-custom-error-page.com" />
    </httpErrors>
  ...
```

and whatever I set as **defaultResponseMode** I cannot get the error page, and instead I'm still retrieving always the IIS error page.

someone knows what's missing?

---

- IIS version 8.5
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

Comment: what is the framework you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Redirecting to custom error pages in Azure Application service doesn't work

- Make sure your `web.config` is deployed in the wwwroot  directory
- Iam able to redirect to `CustomError` page with the below setting in `web.config`  when an error occurs

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/public/404.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

- Under `<system.webServer>` , Make sure you add

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

- Check the path correctly
- Under `wwwroot` folder created one folder named public and added the error.html page. Give the same path  `/public/404.html` in web.config
- Tried to access the page which does not exists, it redirected to the error page

[image]